# Story about a neighborhood 'stuck' in time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm trying to locate a novel, probably young-adult or children's that I read about 15 years ago.

I believe the plot centered around a neighborhood or city block that had become stuck in time, in a similar way to [*Tuck Everlasting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuck_Everlasting).

I think that this was the result of an experiment by the local tinkerer/scientist.

Sorry I can't remember any more details.

Comment: What do you mean by “stuck in time”: anachronisms? No memory from one day to the next? What happens if someone tried to enter or leave the neighborhood? Since you mention *Tuck Everlasting*, how did the other book differ?

Comment: Unfortunately I remember almost no details, and I'm hesitant to put much more incase I'm conflating other books with this one.. I feel like the people in the neighborhood did not age, and carried on with their lives as if it were still the same day the accident occurred (maybe 30 years past?). Still I think they were aware that the outside world was moving on, and there was some understanding of what had happened. I think that the plot revolved around an outsider, probably a child who entered the community. The big difference from 'Tuck' was a more urban/modern setting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*The Prisoner of Pineapple Place*](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0152635599) by [Anne Lindbergh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Lindbergh)? There are more books about the same character by the way ([*The People in Pineapple Place*](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0763617393)).

Blurb found on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0152635599):

> Pineapple Place, an invisible street that moves from city to city and keeps its inhabitants the same age forever, is threatened with change when nine-year-old Jeremiah becomes bored and makes contact with the outside world.

Blurb found on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0763621323):

> The invisible residents of Pineapple Place have lived on the same block for fifty years, where nobody ages and nothing changes - and Jeremiah can’t stand it anymore! Then Mr. Sweeny accidentally moves them to Athens, Connecticut, instead of Athens, Greece, and Jeremiah meets Ruby, a girl from the outside world who can see him in reflections. Will things ever be the same?

It's a long shot, but without details, the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Yes! 99% sure the one I read was "The People in Pineapple Place". Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it was the one you were looking for. The one I had read was The Prisoner of Pineapple Place, I think I still have a battered copy hiding out somewhere :)